# Android, Koin: How to prevent interface bound by viewModel from creating new viewModel instance?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

It's hard to understand what the problem is from the headline - I'll try my best explaining:

I'm using [Koin](https://insert-koin.io) for dependency injection. I'm injecting my `HomeViewModel`into my `HomeFragment` (the viewModel has parameters, but that should be unrelated to the problem):

```
// fragment code

private var viewModelParameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
lateinit var viewModel: VM

...
    
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layout, container, false)
        binding?.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        viewModel = getViewModel(HomeViewModel::class, parameters = viewModelParameters)
        return binding?.root ?: inflater.inflate(layout, container, false)
    }
```

The fragment contains a `RecyclerView`. The recycler's `ViewHolder` declares an interface, that is injected via Koin`s` by inject()`:

```
class MyRecyclerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), KoinComponent {
       private val callback by inject<Callback>()

       fun bind(item: MyItemType) {
           itemView.setOnClickListener { callback.myCallbackFunction(item) }

       }

interface Callback {
        fun myCallbackFunction(item: MyItemType)
    }
}
```

My `HomeviewModel` implements this interface, and I bind it to the viewModel in my `KoinGraph` module via Koin's `bind` DSL method:

```
private val baseModule = module {
        single { androidApplication().resources }
        single { PermissionHelper(androidApplication()) }
        
        ...

        viewModel { HomeViewModel() } bind MyRecyclerviewHolder.Callback::class
}
```

Now, when I click on my recycler item, the callback's `myCallBackFunction` is called, which should trigger the implementation in my `HomeViewModel`. Which it does, **but**: It is not the same instance, but a new `HomeViewmodel`.

My understanding is that Android's `ViewModel`class, if used in the typical way (currently using, without Koin, `by viewModels()` - see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)), should only exist once. But with Koin's `viewModel{}` call, I can create multiple instances, which I think I shouldn't be able to? Or should I (and if yes, why)?

**Anyway, I'd like to bind my callback to the view model I already have (the one the fragment knows of) and not a new instance my fragment doesn't know about.**

How can I achieve that **using Koin and its injection patterns?**

By the way, If I use

```
single { HomeViewModel() } bind MyRecyclerviewHolder.Callback::class
```

instead of

```
viewModel { HomeViewModel() } bind MyRecyclerviewHolder.Callback::class
```

my code works as intended - since I'm forcing my view model to be a singleton that way - which is what I want. But what is the point of the `viewModel{}` command then? And are there any downsides to it? It doesn't feel like what I should be supposed to do but maybe it's totally fine?

Comment: You can try with `by sharedViewModel` but most probably you shouldn't make things on the adapter trigger the view model directly, but make the fragment pass the interface as an argument to the adapter and when that callback is triggered then make the fragment calls the view model method

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The thing is, the code in question is much more complicated, I simplified it for the question. Having the fragment pass the interface of course works, it's just that we're trying to avoid that because it would mean a huge refactor. That's why I try to find a injection solution hat is safe.

Comment: @michpohl I actually understand what you are trying to do and I have a similar case, so have you found an answer ?